# How to get a scrollView's real size which is using the auto layout in different iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, swift

It is quite simple to get a immutable scrollView's real size (maybe you can interpret the "real size" to the "the square that scrollView can display things"),because it is immutable( **without** Layout Constraints ) and you already set the size in code or Interface Builder.

But if I create a Scroll with **autoLayout Constraints**. Once I did this, then I try to run the program with different iPhone  simulator(6s+,6s,5s,) and print the following properties

`[myScroll.frame.width; myScroll.frame.height]`,

`[myScroll.bounds.width; myScroll.bounds.heigth]` or

[`myScroll.contentSize.width; myScroll.contentSize.height]`

They are either (0,0) or (immutableNum,immutableNum)

> Obviously, the size can't be zero or any immutable numbers when iPhone
>   size changed, right?

So how can a access the scrollView's real size? or I should ask which property should I access?

Thank you for your viewing!

Comment: Where do you print those ? you should do it in viewDidAppear or in didLayoutSubviews. Any earlier method will give you not-yet-calculated values

Comment: i printed at viewdidload...

Comment: So that's your problem. It's way too early and the layout is not calculated yet.

Comment: @QuentinHayot. I just try again, and put print statements in viewDidAppear is workless, but it works in viewDidLayoutSubviews! So I guess need take times to figure out the startup order

Comment: Good, I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to access any UI size or position with autolayout, you must do it after the layout is actually calculated.

By experience, the best place to do it is in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.
In `viewDidLoad`, the layout is not calculated yet. That's why you get zero or weird values.